# MSTest failing in 2008 from build script

Tags: msbuild, mstest

Hi guys anyone know what the helll is going on here?

ERROR SNIPPET:

```
Loading ..\LocalTestRun.testrunconfig...
..\LocalTestRun.testrunconfig
Expected type attribute not found.
File ..\LocalTestRun.testrunconfig Line 2 Pos 2.
```

task in a test target in an msbuild script

I have seen other people getting the same error with no fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok have already figured out what is going on. 
I was using $(VS80COMNTOOLS) to look for my MSTest.exe when i should be using $(VS90COMNTOOLS).. sorry!